# Как вытащить правильно документы из коллекции?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Есть:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541da30b975b8b6c095d5fc5"),
    "ts" : 1411228428,
    "close" : true,
    "users" : [ 
        "f69138f086a7c0c", 
        "7e8f5f8fc847bc6"
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "who" : "435a7334bc99ee0",
            "text" : "8d2293cea4566346abf4c8417e43fcf1095bba1a",
            "ts" : 1411243109,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc65807828841259f7e5")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "47bbaf4e168f116",
            "text" : "925896812ad8fcf1dec2f44fd0d4f658ae1316d2",
            "ts" : 1411243110,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc66807828841259f7e7")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "9d809867b2bfcb6",
            "text" : "969e0c6cfb46eb49457faf94c2e2929537ecd737",
            "ts" : 1411243138,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc8199255c301b562fea")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "4c9709ae80f7c75",
            "text" : "8c9563e4dafeaf3b71e3d8cb21fb471e4bc8b012",
            "ts" : 1411243138,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc8199255c301b562fec")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "c100ddf0f2f830b",
            "text" : "451d55c256010800b44f4efb2d65a78ef0f96aca",
            "ts" : 1411243141,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc84b3eeee341f03c6b9")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "b2b1eb64e5eb00e",
            "text" : "6d9f253e9797cbecd66677ba7ca02f800cc64c1b",
            "ts" : 1411243141,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc84b3eeee341f03c6bb")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "e7bcade15805b4b",
            "text" : "d6fd4857baa54be47163144de09c142140a5ea95",
            "ts" : 1411243143,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc879e3d0f902589e2a0")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "98d36fa790d52a4",
            "text" : "5d195be8e25c3c216dd79b406fec38a5a480895d",
            "ts" : 1411243145,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc892eef29502cbaafe3")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "63c767e26afa326",
            "text" : "1dda13865f1f781365538bc681db642ece10c7d0",
            "ts" : 1411243146,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc892eef29502cbaafe5")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "1356a857b9e91b5",
            "text" : "0bb6adb161863b1069a85448bff2008349fafb23",
            "ts" : 1411243242,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddce92eef29502cbaafe7")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "c9e1706f0174726",
            "text" : "c09d81af4ba9c3a2038c193b41548f4b842cfaf1",
            "ts" : 1411243248,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddcf02eef29502cbaafe9")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "de25c398c9d0a56",
            "text" : "17ca3bd1c93a7b4bd930afefc20204f37b6c3b73",
            "ts" : 1411305604,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ed0842eef29502cbaafeb")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "3c7020fcfda12e5",
            "text" : "d521a17692bfa1c05c3e79d2a553a33968c35feb",
            "ts" : 1411306032,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ed22f2eef29502cbaafed")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "d014983828172ba",
            "text" : "ef629535ef6e79a83c5a089cf73bb2da1861cfd0",
            "ts" : 1411320839,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541f0c062eef29502cbaafef")
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541da39e975b8b6c095d5fc6"),
    "ts" : 1411228575,
    "close" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        "f69138f086a7c0c", 
        "7e8f5f8fc847bc6"
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "who" : "df5f65784dbd1dd",
            "text" : "86aabc5a65a26d52586ebf0919f7ae66aa69a02b",
            "ts" : 1411243109,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc65807828841259f7e6")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "74a767908c2ee3a",
            "text" : "6fee943bcd105490c76277d2a4df9999d826ea81",
            "ts" : 1411243110,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc66807828841259f7e8")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "c8d3e0beeb86dba",
            "text" : "307af430f2efbf774955728a5da954997560e403",
            "ts" : 1411243138,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc8199255c301b562feb")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "03ac5abac5b4e4e",
            "text" : "9a026e1e92121650eb1793b3a5844704025270a9",
            "ts" : 1411243138,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc8199255c301b562fed")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "ba8bea569633f34",
            "text" : "46b6227c8326221db2e94c1bea4490c88269bede",
            "ts" : 1411243141,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc84b3eeee341f03c6ba")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "5d2f3acfca7a80a",
            "text" : "86af79eba979c0349c874b8abe7daf52c581956e",
            "ts" : 1411243141,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc84b3eeee341f03c6bc")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "194178107788b1e",
            "text" : "975cc04eee76136da635a732015760dfbf33c5e7",
            "ts" : 1411243143,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc879e3d0f902589e2a1")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "fb10305a2c07079",
            "text" : "633b3783105a548c9529fc3b7091742eeaf120f5",
            "ts" : 1411243145,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc892eef29502cbaafe4")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "ac66edb4412a6b7",
            "text" : "e372fef8368c417d34a13cdf7cee0e2250f1a8a3",
            "ts" : 1411243146,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddc892eef29502cbaafe6")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "8c09f8743f4dde4",
            "text" : "0b81a1f683911e777667204ca14e09fd65eae9cf",
            "ts" : 1411243242,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddce92eef29502cbaafe8")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "f44e24434a6712f",
            "text" : "5a0eefa65944d0ac2b8751a65a456baa4d1c40cb",
            "ts" : 1411243248,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ddcf02eef29502cbaafea")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "06d5ce9d248770f",
            "text" : "2cb1912434a2ce99b4f4a0ae43727855094de1ac",
            "ts" : 1411305604,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ed0842eef29502cbaafec")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "1ba61bb23411547",
            "text" : "f1212ccc2b8f0bac8bf70b02c5b3136dc2c0368e",
            "ts" : 1411306032,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541ed22f2eef29502cbaafee")
        }, 
        {
            "who" : "b24071fc821be59",
            "text" : "1919ae2367a254627da7377dc62d94d1cb2809c1",
            "ts" : 1411320839,
            "_id" : ObjectId("541f0c062eef29502cbaaff0")
        }
    ]
}
```

Это коллекция диалогов.

Нужно:

1. Вытащить последние диалоги, отсортированные по дате, - 15 шт.
2. Вывести в этом же запросе последние документы в messages, отсортированные по дате, - 30 шт.

Просто вывести все, я понял, как:

```
db.dialog.find({
        $and: [
            {users: hash}
        ]
    });
```

Comment: @exec, а зачем здесь $and? Сейчас нет монги под рукой, завтра на работе гляну задачу.

Comment: @ua6xh, Чтобы вытащить диалоги только одного юзера. Может быть, в скайп или телеграм?

Comment: @exec, вообще, не самое лучшее решение для диалогов. Я бы выделил для сообщений отдельную коллекцию, тогда работать с ними было бы проще, чем когда сообщения в массиве.

Comment: @ua6xh, мне посоветовали сделать так.
____

@ua6xh, http://www.slideshare.net/friedo/data-modeling-examples

Comment: @exec - ок, значит надо решать эту задачу. 

[`db.collection.aggregate`][1], 
[`how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb`][2]

Вот помощники, запрос пока собрать не удалось. Первые наброски - что-то типа такого:

`db.dialogs.aggregate([{$unwind:'$messages'},{$sort:{'messages.ts':1}}]);`

Выводит, но пока не то =)



  [1]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Comment: @ua6xh, я вот что нашел http://shakthydoss.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/pagination-with-mongodb/
и по поводу сортировки - я читал что нужно сортировать update и потом вытаскивать уже готовую осортированную коллекцию